# Node.js MongoDB collection.update() callback never called

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Can anyone explain why the callback below is never getting called ?

The update works by the callback is never called.  Did I miss something ?

```
collection.update({_id:partner._id}, 
                    {$set: {
                            groups: newGroups
                          }
                    },
                    { upsert: false, w: 1 },
                    function(err, status){
                      console.log("update callback ");
                      if (err){
                        console.log("Error updating "+err.message);
                        callback(false);
                      } else {
                        console.log("Record updated as "+JSON.stringify(status));
                        callback(true);
                      }
                    }
  );
```

Comment: I think maybe you might be talking about the outer context of the `callback()` function which must be referenced in a wrapping this call that you are not showing here. Typically the expected signature is `function(err,content)` where `err` would be something or `null` rather than the `true/false` values you are returning. You might explain better by giving the full context of the call.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap this in a function with a callback as a param:

```
    //Except for callback as a parameter, every parameter is not compulsory
    function yourFunctionName(id, newGroups, callback) {
      collection.update({
          _id: partner._id
        }, {
          $set: {
            groups: newGroups
          }
        }, {
          upsert: false,
          w: 1
        },
        function(err, status) {
          console.log("update callback ");
          if (err) {
            console.log("Error updating " + err.message);
            callback(false);
          } else {
            console.log("Record updated as " + JSON.stringify(status));
            callback(true);
          }
        }
      )
    }
```

Then call the function like this:

```
yourFunctionName(params, function(result) {
  //Do anything with the result
});
```

If you want to understand how callback functions work, [this](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/) might help you.

Answer (score -1):

For example in node(sailsJs)

```
Model.update({id:'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'},{name:'Flynn'}).exec(function afterwards(err, updated){

if (err) {
//handle error here!
return;
}

console.log('Updated user to have name ' +    updated[0].name);
 });
```